# stack overflow for big input

Tags: stack, overflow, ocaml, stack-overflow, ml

so this is part of my program. it causes a stack overflow when i call bound for numbers whose difference is more than 250000.. how can i fix this? the program works fine for smaller input.. i'm pretty sure the rest of the program is fine. is there a way to rewrite the function so that they work? i would prefer not use for while loops. thanks

```
let rec sqdigits a =
if a = 0 then 0
else ( a mod 10)*( a mod 10) + sqdigits (a/10);;

let rec bound c d =
if c>d then []
else (sqdigits (c))::(bound (c+1) d);;
```

Answer (score 5):

Your functions aren't tail recursive. You don't need to eliminate the recursion (perish the thought in a functional programming language!). You just need to make them tail recursive.

In fact, the number of recursive calls to `sqdigits` is limited by the number of digits in an int, which is quite a small number. So you really only need to fix up `bound`.

I don't want to write the code for you (since this looks like an assignment). But the usual way to make a tail recursive function is to pass the accumulated result as an extra parameter.